# Comparing two dates and avoiding duplication

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I am working on HP ALM where i try to perform this query :

```
SELECT  ONE.ID, ONE.Num_QC_EDF, ONE.Statut, TWO.Proprietaire, ONE.ChangeDate
FROM
(SELECT B.BG_BUG_ID as ID, B.BG_USER_15 as Num_QC_EDF, AP.AP_NEW_VALUE as Statut, BG_RESPONSIBLE as Proprietaire, AL.AU_TIME as ChangeDate
FROM  BUG B
INNER JOIN AUDIT_LOG AL
ON AL.AU_ENTITY_ID = B.BG_BUG_ID
INNER JOIN AUDIT_PROPERTIES AP
ON AL.AU_ACTION_ID = AP.AP_ACTION_ID
AND AL.AU_ENTITY_TYPE = 'BUG'
AND AL.AU_ACTION_ID= AP.AP_ACTION_ID
AND AP_FIELD_NAME= 'BG_STATUS')ONE,
(SELECT B.BG_BUG_ID as ID,B.BG_USER_15 as Num_QC_EDF, AP.AP_NEW_VALUE as Proprietaire , BG_STATUS as Statut , AL.AU_TIME as ChangeDate
FROM  BUG B
INNER JOIN AUDIT_LOG AL
ON AL.AU_ENTITY_ID = B.BG_BUG_ID
INNER JOIN AUDIT_PROPERTIES AP
ON AL.AU_ACTION_ID = AP.AP_ACTION_ID
AND AL.AU_ENTITY_TYPE = 'BUG'
AND AL.AU_ACTION_ID= AP.AP_ACTION_ID
AND AP.AP_FIELD_NAME = 'BG_RESPONSIBLE'
AND B.BG_STATUS = 'TU leger OK')TWO,
BUG B
WHERE
ONE.ID= TWO.ID AND ONE.Num_QC_EDF= TWO.Num_QC_EDF AND ONE.STATUT= TWO.STATUT and ONE.Proprietaire= TWO.Proprietaire and TWO.ChangeDate <= ONE.ChangeDate
Order by BG_BUG_ID, Num_QC_EDF, Proprietaire, ChangeDate
```

I would like to compare the ChangeDate situated in the second sub query to the one in the first sub query which must be  <= ,also the whole query must'nt return duplicated rows in the result of it (PS: distinct doesn't work in nested queries)

I am asking for help.

Comment: Can you add your table structures, some sample data, and expected results to the question as an edit? You seem to have a cartesian join from `BUG B` to the result of the join between `ONE` and `TWO` which might not be helping you, and might be causing your duplicates. Depending on the requirement, this might be solvable with analytics, but it's hard to tell at the moment.

Comment: Youn can refer to this page: http://qtp-automate.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-retrieve-quality-center-bug.html   where you can find all about table structures and relation between them .

Comment: @Alex Poole   You can refer to this page : http://qtp-automate.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-retrieve-quality-center-bug.html  where you can find what you are asking about

Comment: I agree with @AlexPoole, the `BUG B` on the 4th line from the bottom (and the comma on the line above it) are adding the entire BUG table and you are not joining to it anywhere. I would expect your results to include data from your ONE and TWO columns duplicated by the number of records in the BUG table. It's hard to say without sample data however. @user3491503, I reccomend using http://sqlfiddle.com/ to build a sample set to explain your question which will make it easy for users to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you added `BUG B` which doesnt join with other two sub-query tables `ONE` and `TWO`. So, you get hell lot of duplicates.

Without knowing your table structure, it is not possible to alter your query.

In case, you dont want to change your query and still want to get unique records, you can do the following:

```
Select DISTINCT AA.* FROM (*YOUR ENTIRE QUERY*) AA;
```

Above solution is not recomended, you need to join `BUG B` properly to other two tables.